# Add onclick event on chart made with the highcharts library

Tags: javascript, function, events, highcharts, onclick

I was wondering how I can add an on click event on the whole chart made with the highcharts lib.

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: I found this:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-point-events-click-column/

So I tried to do it on the whole chart instead of the options, but it didn't work for me ..

Answer (score 4):

You can use the chart [`click`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.click) event.

Ref:

> Fires when clicking on the plot background. The this keyword refers to
>   the chart object itself. One parameter, event, is passed to the
>   function. This contains common event information based on jQuery or
>   MooTools depending on which library is used as the base for
>   Highcharts.
>
> Information on the clicked spot can be found through event.xAxis and
>   event.yAxis, which are arrays containing the axes of each dimension
>   and each axis' value at the clicked spot. The primary axes are
>   event.xAxis[0] and event.yAxis[0]. Remember the unit of a datetime
>   axis is milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00.

Code:

```
chart: {
    type: 'column',
    events: {
        click: function () {
            alert('chart clicked');
        }            
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DYNhr/

Comment: Is it possible to adjust the configuration later on? So is it possible to create a function which adds the event above to the 'options' / 'configuration' of the chart?

Comment: What you mean by "event above options" ? You can prepare function and then refer like: click: funName